# Vuetify Overflow On A Flex Column Causing Entire Page to Overflow

Tags: flexbox, vuetify.js, css-grid

In my three-column Vuetify layout, I have one column that is very tall. I want only this column to have a scroll bar. However, the code below causes the entire page to overflow! Any help?

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="secondary fill-height">
    <v-row class="fill-height ">
      <v-col class="accent rounded overflow-y-auto" cols="2">
        <div class="text-center">
          Lorem ipsum....super long
        </div>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="primary rounded" cols="5">Editor</v-col>

      <v-col class="success rounded" cols="5">Stage Stuff</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

[image: Current site]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `max-height: calc(100vh - 48px)` style to the div that encloses the long stuff.

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid class="secondary fill-height">
    <v-row class="fill-height">
      <v-col class="accent rounded overflow-y-auto" cols="2">

        <!-- Add max-height to this div so its height won't expand past the viewport's height -->
        <div class="text-center" style="max-height: calc(100vh - 48px)">
          Lorem ipsum....super long
        </div>


      </v-col>
      <v-col class="primary rounded" cols="5">Editor</v-col>
      <v-col class="success rounded" cols="5">Stage Stuff</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

Basically, you just limit the max height of the div when its content gets longer. The `100vh` is the full height of the viewport. The `48px` is the cumulative vertical padding of `<v-container />` and the `<v-col />`.

[See live demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-yalow-8ik8k?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:240-3375)[image]

**Note:**
The `48px` comes from the cumulative vertical paddings/margins/borders of the whole page. In our case, it is the 12px top and bottom padding of the `<v-container/>` plus 12px top and bottom padding of the `<v-col/>`. This is a known trick when we want to achieve a full pager div. You can read more here: https://dev.to/lennythedev/css-gotcha-how-to-fill-page-with-a-div-270j

Comment: Thanks! That was perfect. How did you come up with 48px?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear enough. I have updated my answer to explain where the 48px comes from.